# View won't load in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Don't see what I'm missing here. My javascript isn't throwing any errors, but when I run the main page all I get is a blank screen; it appears that view1.htm isn't loading.

Here's the main page:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
    <!--- This is how you integrate with partials (views)... --->
    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS Views</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <!-- normally would put this in it's own js file and call with script src="" -->
        <script>
            var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);

            demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider
                .when("/",
                        {
                            controller:"simpleController",
                            templateURL:"partials/view1.htm"
                        })
                .when("/view2",
                        {
                            controller:"simpleController",
                            templateURL:"partials/view2.htm"
                        })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/"});
            });


            demoApp.controller('simpleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.customers = [
                        {name:"David Jones", city:"Phoenix"},
                        {name:"James Riley", city:"Atlanta"},
                        {name:"Heedy Wahlin", city:"Chandler"},
                        {name:"Thomas Winter", city:"Seattle"}
                ];

                $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                    $scope.customers.push(
                        {name: $scope.newCustomer.name, city: $scope.newCustomer.city}
                    );
                };
            }]);                
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- placeholder for the views -->
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's partials/view1.htm:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>View 1</h2>
    Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="filter.name" />
    <br/>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:filter.name">{{cust.name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    Customer Name:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
    <br/>
    Customer City:<br/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
    <br/>
    <button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button>
    <a href="#/view2.htm">View 2</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. templateURL should be templateUrl.

Comment: If problem solved with this answer, tag it as correct answer ;)